# Как открыть терминал в Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora

Собственно такой вопрос, как открыть териминал в fedora, т.е. как на многих дистрибутивах в каталоге нажимаешь правую кнопку мыши и выбираешь открыть терминал. А в fedora ничего такого нету, может есть какая нибудь комбинация клавиш?

Comment: а что используется для просмотра файлов? наутилус?

Comment: @Klawik, Вы неправы. В списке приложений все есть. И я как пользователь федоры 23 уверяю - ищите и найдете:)

Comment: в наутилусе есть расширение, которое в меню добавляется "открыть терминал в этой папке". К списку приложений это не имеет отношения.

Comment: @KoVadim да, использую Nautilus

Comment: Ищите пакет Nautilus terminal

Comment: ctrl+alt+T? Ну по крайней мере у меня работает :)

Answer (score 1):

Нажмите комбинацию клавиш ALT+F2
напишите в открывшимся окне gnome-terminal
нажмите ENTER

Answer (score 1):

Параметры -> Клавиатура -> Дополнительные комбинации -> + -> прописываете gnome-terminal и комбинацию клавишь
см. скриншоты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]